# Matching html tags using regex Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following `html` variable containing:

```
"
...
<section>
    aaa
</section>
...
"
```

Using:

```
var output = html.match(/<section>.*[\r\n]*[\n]*<\/section>/g);
```

Gives me a `null` value. I basically want to get all substrings that are in between section tags, given that there are line breaks in between them.

Any clue on why this is not working?
Thanks!

Comment: This link is helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: `.*[\r\n]*[\n]*` only matches a single line with 1+ CR/LF symbols after it. Use `[^]*?`  instead. Or `[\s\S]*?`